# How limit request rate of sqlmap?

Tags: sqlmap, waf

How can we restrict the rate of requests made from sqlmap to the foreign server in order to prevent detection from waf?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the SQLMap man pages:

`--delay=DELAY       Delay in seconds between each HTTP request`

Comment: I think you should consider to set  `--host` option, because some WAF checks headers like Host and SQLmap include information about itself in the host header.

Comment: That would not lower the request rate as per askers question but would add a host header. There are a lot of indications, user-agent being another one, but those are out of the scope for this question :)

Comment: @hmrojas.p +1 this can still be interesting to know as a comment even if not in the scope of the question. It is related since it could help bypass a WAF.